# return objects of a specific type in linq query

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I'm trying to write a linq query that returns all objects of a certain type.

Would something like this work if I wanted to get all the cars that are sedans?

```
Dim cars = From c In carFactory.GetAllcars()
           Select car = carFactory.GetAuto(c.ID)
           Where TypeOf (car) Is Sedan
```

Comment: you have a weird model if you do getAllcars() and it returns a type where to get a car object you have to call GetAuto on the same factory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That will work, but the return type will still be `IEnumerable(Of Car)`.

Instead, you can write `sequence.OfType(Of Sedan)()`; this will filter out non-sedans *and* return an `IEnumerable(Of Sedan)`.

Comment: @999cm999: `sequence` is any IEnumerable or LINQ query.

Answer (score 2):

```
 carFactory.GetAllcars().OfType<Sedan>().Select(car=>car.ID)
```